# Converting python decrypt function to equivalent java

Tags: java, python, encryption

I'm trying to take a functioning Python code and convert it to java. I'm trying to replicated the python function probably to literally on the java side, and have not been able to get it to work.

Example data for input and output

> "encrypted": "V1:tOhwo8540kw=:a+UDgFETMZyyBL3KEYG7Vw==:8ZyjHdUPJ+en4s25gHTqig=="
>
> "decrypted": "netapp123
>
> passphrase = "how can this be acceptable works"

Python code is as follow:

```
import argparse
import base64
import hashlib
import os
import re
import sys

try:
    from Crypto.Cipher import DES
except:
    sys.stderr.write("Error: pycrypto not found - please install before using this script, with e.g. sudo easy_install pycrypto\n")
    sys.exit(1)

def get_derived_key(passphrase, salt, count):
    key = "".join((passphrase[0], salt))
    for i in range(count):
        m = hashlib.md5(key)
        print(key)
        key = m.digest()
    return (key[:8], key[8:])

def decrypt(text, passphrase):
    text_bytes = base64.b64decode(text)
    salt = text_bytes[:8]
    enc_text = text_bytes[8:]

    (dk, iv) = get_derived_key(passphrase, salt, 1000)
    crypter = DES.new(dk, DES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    text = crypter.decrypt(enc_text)

    return re.sub(r'[\x01-\x08]','', text)

def encrypt(text, passphrase):
    salt = os.urandom(8)
    pad_num = 8 - (len(text) % 8)
    for i in range(pad_num):
        text += chr(pad_num)
    (dk, iv) = get_derived_key(passphrase, salt, 1000)
    crypter = DES.new(dk, DES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    enc_text = crypter.encrypt(text)

    return base64.b64encode("".join((salt, enc_text)))
```

And what I have come up with on the java side is this, but it's not working

```
public static String decrypt(String encryptString, String passphrase) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
    byte[] text_bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(encryptString);
    byte[] salt = Arrays.copyOfRange(text_bytes, 0, 8);
    byte[] enc_text = Arrays.copyOfRange(text_bytes, 8, text_bytes.length);

    List<String> derivedKeyList = null;
    try {
        derivedKeyList = getDerivedKey(passphrase, salt, 1000);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        //IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, derivedKeyList[1]);
        byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(enc_text));

        return new String(original);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static List<String> getDerivedKey(String passphrase, byte[] salt, int count) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    String key = String.join(passphrase.substring(0,0), Arrays.toString(salt));
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        md.update(key.getBytes());
        key = Arrays.toString(md.digest());
    }
    
    return List.of(key.substring(0, 8), key.substring(8));
}
```

Comment: Do you think the fact that you are using DES in one piece of code and AES in the other might have something to do with it?

Comment: It's not working? Could you be more specific as to what is not functioning correctly?

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark thanks for pointing that out, I'm also pretty sure the `getDerivedKey` function is not correct, I don't completely understand that function for that matter on the python side

Comment: @pythonier500 for instance the python func. seems to return a string, and with similar function on the java side, that is not gonna work to call the `cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, derivedKeyList[1]);` function for instance.

Comment: Do you absolutely need something as close to a """"literal translation"""" (that idea is probably more complex than it seems, be careful) as possible?

Comment: The input data are not clear to me. It seems to be a string consisting of 4 Base64 encoded parts (separated by :). Which of these should be `text` and which `passphrase`, so that the decryption results in `netapp123`? Anyway, it would make sense to post the Python `encrypt` function as well.

Comment: You need to debug this code step by step and check intermediate values instead of trying to solve it in one go. I don't see why we need to solve this for you. This is a *task* not a question.

Comment: @Topaco I've added the python `encrypt` function in as well. And the `passprase` as well.

Comment: If I use the plaintext `netapp123` and the passphrase `how can this be acceptable works`, the `encrypt` method of the Python2 code returns a Base64 encoded string, e.g. typically `X/snDLeDtw/vk50Mu8MugyYUv0+OToF2` (the output changes each time, of course, as a new salt is generated each time). Anyway, I never get an output that _syntactically_ matches the posted example.